# Add ORDINALITY to expanded JSON array in Postgres 11.7

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, unnest

I'm taking two JSONB arrays, unpacking them, and combing the results. I'm trying to add `WITH ORDINALITY` to the JSON array unpacking. I've been unable to figure out how to add `WITH ORDINALITY`. For some reason, I can't find `WITH ORDINALITY` in the documentation for Postgres 11's JSON tools:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html

I've seen examples using `jsonb_array_elements....WITH ORDINALITY`, but haven't been able to get it to work. First, a functional example based on Postgres arrays:

```
WITH
first AS (
SELECT * FROM
    UNNEST (ARRAY['Charles','Jane','George','Percy']) WITH ORDINALITY AS x(name_, index)
),

last AS (
SELECT * FROM
    UNNEST (ARRAY['Dickens','Austen','Eliot']) WITH ORDINALITY AS y(name_, index)
)

SELECT first.name_ AS first_name,
       last.name_  AS last_name

  FROM first
  JOIN last ON (last.index = first.index)
```

This gives the desired output:

```
first_name  last_name
Charles     Dickens
Jane        Austen
George      Eliot
```

I'm using the `ORDINALITY` index to make the `JOIN`, as I'm combining two lists for pair-wise comparison. I can assume my lists are equally sized.

However, my input is going to be a JSON array, not a Postgres array. I've got the unpacking working with `jsonb_to_recordset`, but have not got the ordinality generation working. Here's a sample that does the unpacking part correctly:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tools.try_ordinality (jsonb, jsonb);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tools.try_ordinality (
     base_jsonb_in         jsonb,
     comparison_jsonb_in   jsonb)

RETURNS TABLE (
    base_text         citext,
    base_id           citext,
    comparison_text   citext,
    comparison_id     citext)

AS $BODY$

BEGIN

RETURN QUERY

WITH
base_expanded AS (

 select *
   from jsonb_to_recordset (
          base_jsonb_in) 
      AS base_unpacked (text citext, id citext)
 ),

comparison_expanded AS (

 select *
   from jsonb_to_recordset (
          comparison_jsonb_in)
      AS comparison_unpacked (text citext, id citext)
 ),

combined_lists AS (
select base_expanded.text       AS base_text,
       base_expanded.id         AS base_id,
       comparison_expanded.text AS comparison_text,
       comparison_expanded.id   AS comparison_id

  from base_expanded,
       comparison_expanded
)

select * 

   from combined_lists;

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
select *  from try_ordinality (
'[
    {"text":"Fuzzy Green Bunny","id":"1"},
    {"text":"Small Gray Turtle","id":"2"}
    ]',

'[
    {"text":"Red Large Special","id":"3"},
    {"text":"Blue Small","id":"4"},
    {"text":"Green Medium Special","id":"5"}
  ]'
);
```

But that's a `CROSS JOIN`

```
base_text    base_id    comparison_text    comparison_id
Fuzzy Green Bunny    1    Red Large Special      3
Fuzzy Green Bunny    1    Blue Small             4
Fuzzy Green Bunny    1    Green Medium Special   5
Small Gray Turtle    2    Red Large Special      3
Small Gray Turtle    2    Blue Small             4
Small Gray Turtle    2    Green Medium Special   5
```

I'm after a pair-wise result with only two rows:

```
Fuzzy Green Bunny    1    Red Large Special    3
Small Gray Turtle    2    Blue Small           4
```

I've tried switching to `jsonb_array_elements`, as in this snippet:

```
WITH
base_expanded AS (

 select *
   from jsonb_array_elements (
          base_jsonb_in) 
      AS base_unpacked (text citext, id citext)
 ),
```

I get back

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is only allowed for functions returning "record"
```

Is there a straightforward way to get ordinality on an unpacked JSON array? It's very easy with `UNNEST` on a Postgres array.

- I'm happy to learn I've screwed up the syntax.
- I can `CREATE TYPE`, if it's of any help.
- I can convert to a Postgres array, if that's straightforward to do.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: WITH ORDINALITY applies to any set-returning functions.  JSON does have set-returning functions you can use it with, but it would be weird to document it there since it is operates there the same way as it does for non-JSON set-returning functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it exactly the same way.

```
with first as (
  select *
  from jsonb_array_elements('[
    {"text":"Fuzzy Green Bunny","id":"1"},
    {"text":"Small Gray Turtle","id":"2"}
    ]'::jsonb) with ordinality as f(element, idx)
), last as (
  select *
  from jsonb_array_elements('[
    {"text":"Red Large Special","id":"3"},
    {"text":"Blue Small","id":"4"},
    {"text":"Green Medium Special","id":"5"}
  ]'::jsonb) with ordinality as f(element, idx)
)
SELECT first.element ->> 'text' AS first_name,
       last.element ->> 'text' AS last_name
FROM first
  JOIN last ON last.idx = first.idx
```