# ERROR: syntax error at or near "with" in jsonb_array_elements Function Call with Ordinality

Tags: postgresql

I can use the `with ordinality` with the function `jsonb_array_elements` without problem when using it as a *table expression* - example taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61708189/4808122)

```
select *
from jsonb_array_elements('[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]'::jsonb) with ordinality as f(element, idx);

"element", idx
{"id": 1}   1
{"id": 2}   2
```

But when I use it as a [function call](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html) I receive an  `ERROR: syntax error at or near "with"`

```
with js as (
 select '[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]'::jsonb as props)
select  
  jsonb_array_elements(props)  with ordinality  as ch 
from js;
```

What is that I'm doing wrong or how can I rewrite the query to get the ordinatlity?

This is PostgreSQL 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with ordinality` can only be used if you put the function call into the FROM clause. The syntax diagram [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT) shows this.

```
with js as (
 select '[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]'::jsonb as props
)
select ch.*
from js
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(props)  with ordinality  as ch
```

Comment: I was fooled by the formulation *When the optional WITH ORDINALITY clause is added to the function call ...*, but yes, the syntax diagram is clear.  Thanks for the support!